# What is the best way to test account balance changes in NEAR smart contracts?

Tags: nearprotocol

I am trying to test that an account's NEAR balance increases and decreases.
`env::account_balance()` doesn’t seem to change even with an `attached_deposit`.

```
#[test]
fn takes_account_deposit() {
  let mut context = get_context();
  context.attached_deposit = 10000000000000000;
  testing_env!(context.clone());
  println!("Account balance before {}", env::account_balance());
  let mut contract = Contract::default();
  contract.take_deposit();
  println!("Account balance after  {}", env::account_balance());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross-contract calls in NEAR are asynchronous, so you need to setup a callback for the `take_deposit` (is my understanding correct that `Contract` is some other contract?). Learn more about promises and cross-contract calls in [the doc](https://www.near-sdk.io/cross-contract/callbacks)

Comment: it seems like you know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/73171108/470749 I appreciate your help. https://www.near-sdk.io/testing/unit-tests doesn't say.

Comment: @vlad can you update your link the 'the doc' as the link is now broken.